PySpark: Add one more layer to BertSentenceEmbeddings model
I'm working with SparkNLP and PySpark, and my objecive is to be able to add another layer to BertSentenceEmbeddings. My input to BertSentenceEmbeddings is a paragraph with multiple sentences which results in an array of final embeddings.
My goal is to add a final pooling layer to BertSentenceEmbeddings so that I get one final embedding for the entire para instead of an array of embeddings per sentence of the para. Is there a pythonic way to access last layer of model via pyspark (or Python) to add a final layer?
This is to manipulate the final embedding I obtained from spark pipeline through dataframe manipulation. I'm interested in making it a part of the model output to streamline processes.
spark = sparknlp.start()

documentAssembler = DocumentAssembler() \
    .setInputCol("text") \
    .setOutputCol("document") \
    .setCleanupMode("shrink")

sentenceDetector = SentenceDetectorDLModel() \
    .pretrained("sentence_detector_dl", "en") \
    .setInputCols(["document"]) \
    .setOutputCol("sentences") \
    .setExplodeSentences(False)

sent_embeddings = BertSentenceEmbeddings.pretrained("sent_bert_wiki_books", "en") \
    .setInputCols("sentences") \
    .setOutputCol("sentence_embeddings")

embeddingsFinisher = EmbeddingsFinisher() \
    .setInputCols(["sentence_embeddings"]) \
    .setOutputCols("finished_embeddings") \
    .setOutputAsVector(True)

Note: I'm using pyspark 3.3.1

where is the code ?
